# Use of shall with "I and we"

Tags: tense, future-tense

> I _ meet my friend tomorrow.

Usually **shall** is used with first person: **I** and **we**.
So, in the above sentence is it fair to use **shall** in the blank.
Actually  my book mentioned the answer as **Will**, therefore I wanted to clarify.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's a big distinction. I've seen that *shall* is also possible in BrE but it's less used than *will.*

Answer (score 3):

Longman English Grammar: Future tense: "will" is used with all persons, but
"shall"can be used as an alternative with "I" and "we". My view: "I/we shall do" is a bit elevated style and it is individual usage. I think that older people may use it more frequently as the younger generations. When shall and will are contracted to 'll you don't see any difference.

Perhaps I should mention why the conjugation of the future tense has this curious irregularity of "shall" in the first person.

Original the verb will refers to volition and "I will do it" had the sense of "I have the firm intention to do it". When "will" was adopted to express future tense "I will do it" became ambiguous, it could express intention or future tense. So "shall" was used in the first person to avoid this ambiguity. By the way Dutch uses "zullen" (shall) as auxiliary verb for all three persons of future tense.

Comment: Yes. And in addition, as a modal of prediction or command, it can be used with any person: *they shall*, *he/she shall*, and of course *[YOU SHALL NOT PASS](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35262/where-did-you-shall-not-pass-come-from)*. Because it is elevated style (and used in the King James Bible, for example), had Gandalf said *you will not pass* it would have been much less forceful and memorable.

Answer (score 2):

From Merriam-Webster entry for shall (emphasis mine...)

> > **Usage Discussion of shall**
> >     From the reams of pronouncements written about the distinction between shall and will—dating back as far as the 17th century—it is clear that the rules laid down have never very accurately reflected actual usage. The nationalistic statements of 18th and 19th century British grammarians, who commonly cited the misuses of the Irish, the Scots, and occasionally the Americans, suggest that the traditional rules may have come closest to the usage of southern England. Some modern commentators believe that English usage is still the closest to the traditionally prescribed norms. *Most modern commentators allow that will is more common in nearly all uses.* The entries for shall and will in this dictionary show current usage.